# What part is left unsolved in the Unknotting problem? (after results of Bar-Natan, Khovanov, Kronheimer and Mrowka)

Tags: knot-theory, computational-topology

- Kronheimer and Mrowka showed that the Khovanov homology detects the unknot.
- Bar-Natan showed a program to compute the Khovanov homology fast: there was no rigorous complexity analysis of the algorithm, but it is estimated by Bar-Natan that the algorithm runs in time proportional to the square root of the number of crossings, so it is even less than linear in the number of crossings.

What I might understand from this, is that if we have:

1. a proof for the correctness of Bar-Natan's algorithm
2. a rigorous algorithm analysis showing the run time of the algorithm is polynomial or less

then we have a proof that the unknotting problem is in P.

I guess this is not really the case.

Is what I assume here true? if not, why? (maybe Bar-Natan's algorithm is not deterministic?)

Comment: "Bar-Natan showed a program to compute the Khovanov homology fast:" What is the reference for this, please?

Comment: Hi Sam, here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606318

Comment: Omri - Thanks for this.  I've posted a short answer below.

Comment: Don't forget infinite knots.

Comment: $O(\sqrt{\text{crossings}})$ does not give time enough to even look at all the crossings.

Comment: The unknotting problem was solved a long time ago, it sounds like you are interested in polynomial-time unknot recognition.    The exponential-time algorithms using normal surface theory have "most of the time" better than exponential run-times.  To me it seems like this route is still the most enticing way to make progress on your problem.

Comment: @RyanBudney: How good are they, usually? Better than the Bar-Natan's mentioned "usually $O(\exp(\sqrt n))$ time" algorithm?

Comment: @MikeMiller: I have not read Bar Natan's paper.  How does he determine his "usually" comment, is this a general statement or one derived by computing a few examples?   If you give me an answer to that I should be able to answer your question.  The "usually" for the normal surface / triangulation techniques is a very high probability for any knot you can draw in a short amount of time.  And that conclusion is reached by computing for plenty of examples.  If you have any complicated knots I'd be happy to run Regina over it.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I haven't read it either; my impression is that it's heuristic, but that many examples have been computed. I was just hoping you could quantify how good normal surface theory is most of the time when you say it's usually better than exponential: is it usually polynomial? Usually $O(\exp(\sqrt n))$? Etc.

Comment: @MikeMiller: in practice it looks like a low-degree polynomial-time complexity. This is one paper that starts to quantify these observations: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6080

Answer (score 39, accepted):

EDIT: Marc Lackenby has just announced a quasi-polynomial time algorithm. That is, given an $n$—crossing diagram, the algorithm takes $n^{O(\log(n))}$ time to either find a spanning disk (proving the knot is trivial) or a hierarchy (proving the knot is non-trivial).

PREVIOUS: A quick skim of the paper you linked to finds (on paragraph two of page two) comments by Bar-Natan suggesting that his improvement should take time $\exp({\sqrt{n}})$, beating the naive algorithm (taking time $\exp(n)$). That is, the improvement hopefully makes an exponential algorithm subexponential. He is not claiming a sublinear algorithm.

Comment: Sam, thanks for the answer, it appears I had a confusion about the values of C1 and b which are given in the introduction of Bar-Natan's paper.

Comment: Two minor points to add to this: First, I assume it's $\exp(c\sqrt n)$ for some (possibly unknown) constant $c$, rather than necessarily $c=1$. And second, $\exp(c\sqrt n)$ is a typical time bound for many NP-complete problems on planar graphs (and knot diagrams are, essentially, planar graphs). So one shouldn't conclude that this subexponential time bound is low enough to make polynomial time likely — many other problems have the same bound and are still very unlikely to be polynomial.

Comment: Here's a link to the slides from Marc's talk: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/quasipolynomial-talk.pdf

Comment: And the video of Marc's talk is here: https://video.ucdavis.edu/media/quasipolynomial-unknot/1_w3i5jvqi

Answer (score 41):

To strengthen Sam Nead's answer, note that it is trivial to compute the Jones polynomial from the Khovanov homology. It is known that computing (or even approximating) the Jones polynomial is #P-hard:

- Kuperberg, Greg, *How hard is it to approximate the Jones polynomial?*, Theory Comput. 11 (2015), 183–219. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.0512.pdf
- Vertigan, Dirk, *The computational complexity of Tutte invariants for planar graphs*, SIAM J. Comput. 35 (2005), no. 3, 690–712.

Thus any approach along these lines will definitely not give an efficient algorithm for detecting the unknot (assuming standard complexity-theory conjectures).

Note that Jones conjectured that the Jones polynomial itself detects the unknot, but of course that still won't give an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 24):

This isn't directly what you ask, but it's also worth noting that unknot detection is in $\text{NP} \cap \text{co-NP}$, that is, there are polynomial-checkable certificates that will show that either a knot is the unknot or that the knot is not the unknot. The $\text{NP}$ certificate uses normal surface theory:

- Ian Agol, Joel Hass, William Thurston, *The computational complexity of knot genus and spanning area*. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. **358** (2006), no. 9, 3821–3850.

The $\text{co-NP}$ certificate is currently conditional on the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, and is based on finding representations of the knot group:

- Greg Kuperberg, *Knottedness is in NP, modulo GRH*. Adv. Math. **256** (2014), 493–506.

(There ought to be another proof of the $\text{co-NP}$ result using normal surface theory and the notion of hierarchies. Ian Agol sketched that some time ago, but the details are difficult.)

The class $\text{NP} \cap \text{co-NP}$ is relatively small, and this gives reasons to believe that detecting the unknot is in $\text{P}$.

(I would have made this a comment, but I think it's too long for that.)

Comment: Marc Lackenby has announced a proof that this problem is in co-NP independent of GRH. Marc Lackenby - The efficient certification of knottedness and Thurston norm - http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00290

Comment: I think it may be better to say being in the class $\text{NP}\cap\text{co-NP}$ gives reason to believe that detecting the unknot is not $\text{NP-complete}$, not that detecting the unknot is in $\text{P}$.  Factoring is in $\text{NP}\cap\text{co-NP}$.

Comment: @MarkS, fair enough, but isn't also true that some people thing that factoring might also be in P?

Comment: Well, factoring is in $\text{BQP}$ - a quantum computer can factor in polynomial time. However, although I'm not sure I would understand fully, I believe quantum computers are not known to give a speed-up on knottedness, and through Kuperberg above, this may be unlikely. A "[quantum money](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.5127.pdf)" scheme has been constructed based on this theoretical difficulty. Also, if $\text{P}\ne\text{NP}$, then there must be problems [intermediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) between $\text{P}$ and $\text{NP}$, and unknotting may be a good candidate.

Comment: Whereas, if a problem in $\text{NP}\cap\text{co-NP}$ or $\text{AM}\cap\text{co-AM}$ were $\text{NP-complete}$, then the whole polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level.  As I understand, proving that the polynomial hierarchy does not collapse to a particular level is thought to be harder than proving $\text{P}\ne\text{NP}$.